# How to pass async props from parent-component to child-component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-component

**Imagine this simple scenario below in React:**

[image]

In this example, we have a single parent component with a child component. When the parent component begins instantiation it needs to make a request to get a childId. The request could or could not be async. In my particular case I'm using electron.

*After* the parent id retrieves the childId I then want to pass that childId as a prop to the child component which then makes another request to retrieve it's own state.

This is the functionality that I would like to achieve. The issue that I've been wrestling with for the past few hours revolves around the retrieval of the childId. Unfortunately, React creates the child component before the parent component retrieves the childId. Therefore the child component is unable to retrieve it's own state.

**I would like to see if there is a way I could delay the child-component from rendering until the parent component retrieves the childId.**

**ParentComponent**

```
interface IState {
ticketId: number;
}

export class TicketOrchestrator extends React.Component<{}, IState> {
    public state: IState = {
        ticketId:0
    };

public render(): React.ReactNode {
    const onPrevious = () => console.log("FromPrevious");
    const onNext = () => console.log("FromNext");
    return (
    <div> 
        <Ticket ticketId={this.state.ticketId} previous={onPrevious} next={onNext}/>
    </div>
    );
}

public componentDidMount(): void {
    ipcRenderer.on("ticketOrchestrator", this.onMessage);
}

public componentWillUnmount(): void {
    ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners("ticketOrchestrator");
}

private onMessage = (event: any, ticketId: any) => {
    console.log("TicketId", ticketId);
    this.setState({ ticketId: ticketId });
};
}
```

**Child Component**

```
interface IState{
    id: number,
    header: {
        ticketNumber: string,
        title: string,
        date: Date
    },
    body: {
        content: string,
    }
}

interface IProps{
    ticketId: number,
    previous: any,
    next: any
}

export class Ticket extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
    public state:IState = {
        id: this.props.ticketId,
        header: {
            ticketNumber: "",
            title: "",
            date: new Date()
        },
        body: {
            content: "",
        }
    };

public render(): React.ReactNode {
    const handleClickNext = () => this.props.previous();
    const handleClickPrevious = () => this.props.next();
    return (
    <div>
        <button onClick= {handleClickPrevious} >Previous</button>
        <button onClick= {handleClickNext}>Next</button>
        <div>
            <h2>{this.state.header.title}</h2>
            <h4>{this.state.header.date.toLocaleTimeString()}</h4>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>{this.state.body.content}</p>
            <p>Id: {this.state.id}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Thanks,
Ruben

Comment: Can you add a code example to this question so we can help troubleshoot?

Comment: Hey Nick, code example added.

Comment: So is `ticketId` what you're waiting for before rendering the child?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In my use case I would like the parent component aka TicketOrchestrator to fetch the ticketId and then render the child component aka Ticket. That way when the Ticket component renders it already has a valid TicketId that can be used to retrieve itself from some backend service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `ticketId` is always `0` before it has been loaded, you can just show alternative/loading content while your `ticketId` is `0`:

```
<div>
  {this.state.ticketId === 0 ? (
    <>Loading...</>
  ) : (
    <Ticket
      ticketId={this.state.ticketId}
      previous={onPrevious}
      next={onNext}
    />
  )}
</div>;
```

Comment: Okay, so you're not aware of any type of method to retrieve the ticketId in the parent component prior to calling the render function. It would seem cleaner to me if I could just prevent the whole rendering of the children until I have a valid prop.

Comment: Oh woops I just now noticed this is in the parent component. Excellent. This seems like what I want. Thanks.